# Can you call the numba.cuda.random device function in user-created numba CUDA device functions?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I have a cuda kernel and several device functions in numba for a project. When I try to call `xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32` from the

`numba.cuda.random` module. Whenever I try to call this, I get:

```py
import numba
from numba import cuda 
from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states
from numba.cuda.random import xoroshiro128p_uniform_float64

@cuda.jit('void(float32[:,:])', device=True) 
def device(rng_states):  
    thread_id = cuda.grid(1) 
    probability = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float64(rng_states, thread_id) 
     
@cuda.jit() 
def kernel(rng_states): 
    device(rng_states) 
 
 
BPG = 10 
TPB = 10 
rng_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(BPG * TPB, seed=42069) 
kernel[TPB, BPG](rng_states)
```

> ```
>  TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) 
>  Untyped global name 'xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
> ```

Has anyone successfully called imported functions in a CUDA device function on numba before?

Comment: no you can't.  The [numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html) describes what you can do/use in CUDA kernel code.  However, if random numbers is what you want, there is [example numba code](https://numba.discourse.group/t/random-number-generation-on-the-gpu/309/3) for doing that (it's a special case, basically).

Comment: @RobertCrovella that's what im trying to do... the xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32 is the function i'm trying to call. it's only throwing the above error

Comment: @RobertCrovella edited title to make it more descriptive

Comment: The code I linked gives an example.  If you're having trouble, you're expected to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @RobertCrovella code added

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
@cuda.jit('void(float32[:,:])', device=True) 
def device(rng_states):
```

That signature is incorrect and also unnecessary.  There is no reason that I know of to think that `rng_states` is or should be a 2D `float32` array.

Do this:

```
@cuda.jit(device=True) 
def device(rng_states):
```

A few other things I noticed which are not the proximal issue:

A kernel launch specifies blocks per grid first, then threads per block.  So this might be incorrect if you modify things in the future:

```
kernel[TPB, BPG](rng_states)
```

To my eye it is better written as:

```
kernel[BPG, TPB](rng_states)
```

Finally, your question states:

> When I try to call xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32

but your code reflects:

```
probability = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float64(
```

Regarding this question:

> Has anyone successfully called imported functions in a CUDA device function on numba before?

In the general case, functions from a python import may or may not be usable in CUDA device code.  (Most are [not usable](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html).) This random number generator, provided by `numba` for this purpose, might be called a "special case".